# JsonLogOn via https

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl

I've just introduced SSL to my MVC website. I made the whole default AccountContorller use it.  It works fine unless I'm currently on **http** page and try to log on with ajax (the logon action is vredirected to **httpS**). This popup logon window doesn't even show up.

For the controller a used a custom attribute:

```
public class RequireSSL : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(NoSSL), true) ||
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalSSL), true))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
        if (!req.IsSecureConnection && (!req.IsLocal || Properties.Settings.Default.UseSSLForLocalRequests))
        {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
            {
                Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                Port = Properties.Settings.Default.HttpsPort,
            };
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

How can I make it work?

**EDIT**

The whole rest was generated by MVC. (Project with built in authentications)

That's the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Labels.LogOn, "LogOn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "logonLink", data_dialog_title = "Identification" })
```

JS somehow hooks into that link and performs ajax logon . Probably with this code: (JajaxLogin.js - also out of the box)

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />

$(function () {
    // Cache for dialogs
    var dialogs = {};

    var getValidationSummaryErrors = function ($form) {
        // We verify if we created it beforehand
        var errorSummary = $form.data('validation-summary-errors');
        if (!errorSummary) {
            errorSummary = $('<div class="validation-summary-errors"><span>Please correct the errors and try again.</span><ul></ul></div>')
                .insertBefore($form);

            // Remember that we created it
            $form.data('validation-summary-errors', errorSummary);
        }

        return errorSummary;
    };

    var formSubmitHandler = function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
        if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray())
                .done(function (json) {
                    json = json || {};

                    // In case of success, we redirect to the provided URL or the same page.
                    if (json.success) {
                        location = json.redirect || location.href;
                    } else if (json.errors) {
                        var errorSummary = getValidationSummaryErrors($form);

                        var items = $.map(json.errors, function (error) {
                            return '<li>' + error + '</li>';
                        }).join('');

                        var ul = errorSummary
                            .find('ul')
                            .empty()
                            .append(items);
                    }
                });
        }

        // Prevent the normal behavior since we opened the dialog
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    var loadAndShowDialog = function (id, link, url) {
        var separator = url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?';

        // Save an empty jQuery in our cache for now.
        dialogs[id] = $();

        // Load the dialog with the content=1 QueryString in order to get a PartialView
        $.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
            .done(function (content) {
                dialogs[id] = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>')
                    .hide() // Hide the dialog for now so we prevent flicker
                    .appendTo(document.body)
                    .filter('div') // Filter for the div tag only, script tags could surface
                    .dialog({ // Create the jQuery UI dialog
                        title: link.data('dialog-title'),
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        width: link.data('dialog-width') || 300
                    })
                    .find('form') // Attach logic on forms
                        .submit(formSubmitHandler)
                    .end();
            });
    };

    // List of link ids to have an ajax dialog
    var links = ['logonLink', 'registerLink'];

    $.each(links, function (i, id) {
        $('#' + id).click(function (e) {
            var link = $(this),
                url = link.attr('href');

            if (!dialogs[id]) {
                loadAndShowDialog(id, link, url);
            } else {
                dialogs[id].dialog('open');
            }

            // Prevent the normal behavior since we use a dialog
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You seem to have talked about some popup not showing in your question. Could you show the relevant code that you are using to show this popup? It looks like you are violating the same origin policy which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov This is the popup automatically generated by MVC. See the edit please.